# How can I draw this figure in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Here's my attempts,

```
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[very thin, gray!15!black, dashed] (1,0) -- (1,5.5) (5,0) --(5,5.5);
\draw[thick, black!50!gray]  (1,0) rectangle (2,3) (2,0) rectangle (3,4) (3,0) rectangle (4,4.6) (4,0) rectangle (5,5);
 \path  (1,0) node[below]{$a$} (5,0) node[below]{$b$} (3,0) node[below]{ $a+k(\frac{b-a}{n})$}(3,5)  node[font=\normalsize]{$f(x)$}; 
\draw[thick,-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0); 
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem now is the curve.

[image]

Using TikZ how can I draw this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is not a ''Do that for me'' site. Please show us what have tried so far.

Comment: You might check out the section in the PGF manual on data visualizaton.

Comment: @rsa-krypto I've added my own code to draw it!

Comment: Related : A rough version. [Riemann Integral on Tikz with commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554044/138900)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please change the title of your question so that it clearly indicates the problem posed, making it easier for search engines to index it.

Comment: @AndréC Can u suggest an edit ?

Comment: @Amölme Normally you can edit the title and content of your question without asking permission by clicking on the `edit` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something you can achieve by choosing a function for your curve.
Then, everything is defined with respect to this function declared with the `declare function` key and can be changed to adapt to the needs of the user.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {localplot(\x) = sqrt(2*\x + 1);}
    ]
        
        \draw[-Latex] (-1, 0) -- (5, 0);
    
        \draw[
            domain  = -0.25:4.25,
            samples = 200
        ] plot ({\x}, {localplot(\x)});
        
        \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,3.5} {
            \draw (\x, 0) rectangle ({\x + 0.5}, {localplot(\x)});
        }
    
        \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0, {localplot(4.25) + 0.1});
        \draw (4, -0.2) -- (4, {localplot(4.25) + 0.1});
        
        \fill (0, 0) circle (0.05)
            node[below right] {$a$};
        \fill (4, 0) circle (0.05)
            node[below left] {$b$};
            
        \fill (2, 0) circle (0.05)
            node[below] {$a + k\left(\frac{b - a}{n}\right)$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This code yields:

[image]